# How to calculate the value of an arithmetic expression

Tags: php

I've just completed a simple calculator exercise in PHP, using a switch statement, to handle 4 math operator functions (*, /, +, -)

I wanted to modify my calculator, so I can enter expressions and calculate the result. Here is my modified code

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
<p>Value:<br/>
<input type="text" name="first"></p>
<button type="submit">Calculate</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
// collect value of input field
$a = $_REQUEST['first'];

if (empty($a)) {
    echo "<br>field is empty<br><br><br><br>";
} else {
    echo $a;
}
}
?>
```

How do I compute the evaluation of the expression entered into the `first` form field?

Comment: I've tried to re-cast this question to better express its intent. I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in your case simply do this

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
// collect value of input field
$a = $_REQUEST['first'];

if (empty($a)) {
    echo "<br>field is empty<br><br><br><br>";
} else {
    $a = eval('return '.$a.';');
    echo $a;
}
}
?>
```

Comment: it works for only two number addition. any pointers bout how can i modify it for more operations type? @codingsoul

Comment: else { $a = eval('return '.$a.';'); echo $a; }

Comment: hey bro, its works thanks. i adding only code from your comment. My code now is below:                   if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {$a = $_REQUEST['first']; $a = eval('return '.$a.';'); echo $a; } @codingsoul

Comment: why it isnt recomended? i have try more difficult calculation and its works good @codingsoul

Comment: you're welcome. I know it works even in difficult calculation why i said that it isn't recommended, because it allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. Just don't pass any user provided data into it without properly validating it. I have edited the code please mark it as accepted.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment and I can tell you how but in this moment I can give you full code answer:

You can use regex to remove everything besides numbers, `dots for numbers as` `12.16237831 and operations as +,-,/,*`.

After than you can do same to say divide string into an array by some of those operations as:

```
2+2 into $anArray = [2,2];
```

And check which operation was found between and then use it to do what you want.

Comment: is there any way to return the removed operations? so the calculation can keep working? @NoNameNeedToKnow

Comment: Yes with ajax call. Or simply everything without php with just javasccript.

Comment: im using eval instead, and its works. thanks bud  for commenting :D i will learn ajax later :D @NoNameNeedToKnow